# ENOENT: nosuch file or directory, scandir C:\Users\user\App\node_modules whenever trying to run yarn start

Tags: react-native, npm, expo

When trying to run a `react-native` project with `expo` I get the following error:

> ENOENT: nosuch file or directory, scandir 'C:\Users\user\app\node_modules'

I've tried:

- removing `node_modules` from the app directory.
- `npm install` in app directory
- uninstalling expo and reinstalling
- uninstalling `npm` globally and reinstalling
- uninstalling `yarn` and reinstalling
- clearing cache of `yarn` and `npm`

I expect the `react-native` project to work like it does on my other computer. I built the `expo` `react-native` app using `init expo` and now ANY project I try to start comes up with this weird error.

Any ideas on what to else try?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you running in that project directory?

Comment: expo init  yourproject => cd yourproject => expo start

Comment: Hi hong,
Yes running Yarn in that dir.
On your second comment, do you mean try creating another proj?

Comment: Yes, follow the new project as above.

Comment: Hi hong, yes that's worked. I've simply copied over the .js file and its now working.

Comment: If my answer is helpful, could you choose my answer below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new project and run it in the default order.

> expo init yourproject => cd yourproject => expo start